# Reading array from different ways gives me different results

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux

I try to use redux to store my datas and use datas from the global state. The problem is that I don't understand why the third console.log() dosen't work.

```
const results = this.props.popMovies

/* work */ console.log(this.props.popMovies[0].title)

                                    for (var i = 0; i < this.props.popMovies.length; i++)
/* work */ console.log(this.props.popMovies[i].title);

/* dosen't work */ console.log(...results.title)
```

If someone could explain to me why, it can help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing `console.log(...results.title)` would mean that you are trying to spread `result.title` but `title` doesn't exists as a property of `result` but within objects inside result array

You would need to retrieve the titles first before spreading them. For that you can use spread syntax with map

```
console.log(...results.map(item => item.title));
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `results` is an `array` and doesnot have any title property `title`. So you actually doing

```
console.log(...undefined)
```

First you can array of all titles using [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and then pass it to `console.log`

```
console.log(...results.map(x => x.title))
```

Here is demo using demo Array.

```js
const result = [{title:"title1"},{title:"title2"},{title:"title3"}]

console.log(...result.map(x => x.title))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because accessing the `title` property of the `results` array takes precedence over the spread operator on `...results.title` which basically means that the above code is trying to spread the `results.title` object/array which does not exist.

Try this instead:

```
result.forEach(item => console.log(item.title))
```